# Closure Compiler - can a++ >= 3 become ++a > 3?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, post-increment, pre-increment

I admit that I asked a question about why Closure Compiler does not shorten certain code which looks shortenable at first sight a few days ago already, but that reason is not applicable in this case and I'm not really sure why it isn't shortened here.

What code I have is:

```
var a = 0;
function b() {
    return a++ >= 3;
}
```

Now there is pre-incrementing and post-incrementing. The difference is the return value - `a++` returns `a` and *then* increments it, `++a` first increments `a` and *then* returns it.

What this comes down to is that my code could be shortened to (ignoring whitespace removal):

```
var a = 0;
function b() {
    return ++a > 3;
}
```

However, Closure Compiler does not seem to alter (or recognise) this.

My question therefore is: what side effects could `++a >` have when used instead of `a++ >=`?

Comment: Why would you want it to do that? I can't see how it will improve performance in any way.

Comment: Not because of performance, but because of code length. Closure Compiler is there to shorten code by removing whitespace and a lot more, so `a++>=3` could be shortened to `++a>3`. Not very exciting but I was just wondering.

Comment: you need to meet 2 conditions and gain is very little so they probably didn't even waste their time or are focused on more important things...

Comment: That could be just the case, but is it correct that they both expressions are equal to each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There *is* a particular edge-case for this construct (but not for 3).

It occurs because JavaScript stores numbers as IEEE-754 float-point 64-bit doubles and "only" has a guaranteed "exact" integer-representation up to 2^53 (although implementations may have lee-way to have a higher range, I do not know).

This is on Firefox 4:

```
a = 2e53
a++ >= 2e53 // true

a = 2e53
++a > 2e53 // false
```

Real question is *what realized gain* would such a very particular transformation have? :-0

Happy coding.

Comment: In Firebug, Firefox 3.6 `(Number.MAX_VALUE + 1) === Number.MAX_VALUE` is `true`

Comment: In Chrome too, however `Number.MAX_VALUE + 1e308 === Infinity`. Also Chrome seems to go up to `e+308`.

Answer (score 2):

It’s safe to apply this size-optimisation if the right-operand (`3` in your example) is a **constant integer** in the range **[-2<sup>52</sup>, 2<sup>52</sup>]**. In any other case (for example, if the right-operand is fractional or very large), it is not safe.

I would imagine that Closure does not implement this optimisation because:

- it requires a lot of checking to ensure that the optimisation is safe,
- it only applies in very specific circumstances that probably don’t come up very often, and
- It only saves a single character, which hardly seems worth the bother.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check all of the edge conditions yourself?

```
function b(a) {
    return a++ >= 3;
}

function b2(a) {
    return ++a > 3;
}

console.log(b(2) === b2(2))
console.log(b(3) === b2(3))
console.log(b(4) === b2(4))
```

The output is `true` in each case.

Comment: Yes, so my actual question was why Closure Compiler ignores it.